# Difference between libglfw3.a and

Tags: opengl, glfw

I found a instruction for using glfw in Xcode (link below)
(https://handonch.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/how-to-use-glfw-in-xcode/)

It says use 'libglfw3.a' but only I can see in same directory was 'libglfw.3.2.dylib'.
So I used it instead of 'libglfw3.a' and Everything works fine.

I think only '.dylib' file was there not a '.a' file because I used home-brew instead of cmake when I install glfw(I don't know cmake well)

Can anyone explain me difference between those two files? 
(libglfw3.a / libglfw.3.2.dylib)

Comment: also I would appreciate it If you explain difference between installing glfw via 'home-brew' and 'cmake'. thanks you :)